# How to position <div> element absolute from browser window?

Tags: html, css

I have a big html page, which requires lots of scrolling. I'd like to have a `<div>` element shown absolute to browser window, so that it is always visible, no matter where I scroll the page.

I tried using css for div element `position: absolute;` but it does not help in this case.

How can it be done?

Comment: why not `position:fixed`?

Comment: have you tried position: fixed; ?

Comment: Post some relevant code in a fiddle.

Comment: `position:absolute` will be relative to the page, `position:fixed` is relative to the browser screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `position: fixed` for achieving that

Here is a small tutorial

http://davidwalsh.name/css-fixed-position

Answer (score 1):

Use `position:fixed`

Here is a fiddle you can reference.

http://jsfiddle.net/muLM8/

Comment: I'm a bit confused, (apart for the demo) how is this answer better than Clyde's answer?

Comment: Not sure why you are confused, I was creating the demo while the two answers before me were posted. Didn't see till after my post. If it makes you feel better, I gave his answer an up-vote.

Comment: Oh, and it's always better to have a demo. Lets the asker play with it and learn. At least that's my opinion.

Comment: heheh :D sure I might agree, just, next time first shoot the answer and than play with valuable demoes! :) Will get you rep sky high :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `position:fixed` would be a great choice, see [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r9p3C/) here.

However, for compatibility reason, IE 6 doesn't support `position:fixed`, you should use some javascript hack to do so.

Comment: I buried IE7 long time ago. So you should IE6 ;)

Comment: You will be surprised by market share of IE 6 in China, where there is a need, there is a bunch of front-end developers make the compatible.

Comment: I'd rather forget about some China's governmental offices working still in IE6, and rather mention the issues related to `fixed` and mobile viewport.

Comment: You guys will never know how jealousy we are when we have to make everything look like exactly the same in IE6/7.

Answer (score 0):

Use the property,

position:fixed

It is the css property to position the element  relative to the browser window